# Listen to port from docker

Tags: docker, port

I have a php app running inside a docker container. The app uses SMTP for mailing. Pre-docker we used a tool called FakeSMTP that allowed us to intercept outgoing e-mails.

We entered the port 2525 into the FakeSMTP tool, and it would listen on this port for e-mails. Whenever our app would send mails on port 2525 we could intercept them. I want to do the same, but with docker.

I tried mapping the port (`-p 2525:2525`) from docker to host, but that means that the port can not be bound to by any other tools.

Is expose the way to go?

Or is this even possible?

Comment: do you have a reproducer (Dockerfile, run commands...) ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not map the port to something else on the container, then have FakeSMTP listen to that other port?

-p 41950:2525

Then have FakeSMTP listen to port 41950 and send the intercepted mail out on port 2525.

Comment: Because if I do this mapping, the port is already taken, FakeSMTP cannot bind to it anymore. The longer I think about this, the more it seems, that this cannot be done.